# Can I call native code FROM java when using android_native_app_glue.c

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I am looking at the MoreTeapots sample:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/MoreTeapots

and I see that is easy to call a Java method from the C++ code using android_native_app_glue.c by using this method:

```
jclass clazz = jni->GetObjectClass(app_->activity->clazz);
jmethodID methodID = jni->GetMethodID(clazz, "updateCamera", "(FFF)V");
jni->CallVoidMethod(app_->activity->clazz, methodID, x, y, z);
```

yet, can I do the reverse in that sample?

Declare a function into java code and that calls the native code. Notice that sample uses "glue"; therefore, the answer is not just these steps:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html

it is different. I see no hooks from java to glue, only from glue to java. I believe glue is running in its own thread.

any leads?

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could declare a callback in your native code

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_package_Activity_nativeCallback(JNIEnv* jenv, jobject obj);
```

And then from Java code, just declared as native

```
native void nativeCallback();
```

Remember that this execute in main thread, and you should send a command to the background thread to process.

Best regards.

Comment: that does not work with "glue" see my following post

Comment: On the create method of your main activity load your library, eg

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        System.loadLibrary("MoreTeapotsNativeActivity");
        ...
     }

Answer (score 0):

That does not work with "glue". If you look at the sample I mentioned it is different. It uses glue. So I added to the java code:

```
public native void nativeCallback();
```

then to native:

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sample_moreteapots_MoreTeapotsNativeActivity_nativeCallback(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sample_moreteapots_MoreTeapotsNativeActivity_nativeCallback(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
int i = 0;
return;
}
```

it compiled and linked. But when I tried to invoke the method from Java I get this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sample.moreteapots, PID: 31733 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.sample.moreteapots.MoreTeapotsNativeActivity.nativeCallback()
(tried Java_com_sample_moreteapots_MoreTeapotsNativeActivity_nativeCallback
and Java_com_sample_moreteapots_MoreTeapotsNativeActivity_nativeCallback__)
```